# How to reduce size of image from 5MB to 2MB in WP8.1 app using c#

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

I want to reduce the size of image like if image size in more then 2MB i want to reduce it to 2MB.
i used following code:

```
StorageFile file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync(imagePath);
StorageItemThumbnail thumbnail2 = await file.GetThumbnailAsync(ThumbnailMode.PicturesView, 500, ThumbnailOptions.ResizeThumbnail;
```

but this thumbnail2 give very small size image i want at least size of 2MB but this give size in Kb.
What will be the code to get image of size of 2MP?????

Comment: I don't think you will be able to specify a target size in MB, this will depend on how the image can be compressed. If someone sends you a 5MB file with all white this certainly will be smaller than a picture with much more complexity. And I think it is not very surprising that a thumbnail picture is small ...

Comment: You'll have to implement this yourself - compute half the dimensions and resize the image to that size. If under 2MB, done. If over 2MB, half the dimensions again (I'd say work with the dimensions and continue to perform the resizing from the original image, rather than resizing a resized image). Repeat until done.

Comment: Why the thumbs down?  It's a good question, and the OP has shown that he's trying to figure it out.  So, what gives?

Answer (score 2):

Since GetThumbnailAsync second parameter is the size in pixels just try some bigger values here until you get the result you want.
To start with: 2MiB = 2*2^20 Bytes. If each Pixel is encoded with 3 Bytes, assuming no compression, this would be (2*2^20)/3 = 699050 Pixels. So try this and if the result is to big/small change the value as needed.

Comment: This will give me very small image. Can i fixed size up to 2Mb.